# NHibernate: map class with several inheritance fields

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following entities in my project which I want to map using NHibernate Attributes:

```
public interface IContent
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

[Class]
public class Book : IContent
{
    [Id(...), Column(...), Generator(...)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

[Class]
public class Collection : IContent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

[Class]
public class Reader : IUser
{
    [Id(...), Column(...), Generator(...)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}

[Class]
public class ReaderGroup : IUser
{
    [Id(...), Column(...), Generator(...)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(...)]
    public virtual ISet<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
}
```

And now I want to implement a unified access control mechanism:

```
public class AccessPermission
{
    [Id(...), Column(...), Generator(...)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IContent Object { get; set; }

    public virtual IUser Subject { get; set; }
}
```

The trick is that there are **two** fields which accept different types of values: `Object` and `Subject`. I have previously used `Discriminator` and `Subclass` attributes, but then there was only one field with inherited types, not two or more.

Is there a smart way to implement such a case?

Comment: Can you describe how you are modeling this in the database?  There are several different ways to approach this.

Comment: This is a new project, so I'm just creating classes and letting NHibernate create the schema for me. Any approach on the database side will do.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate doesn't really play nice with interfaces as the way it works is by creating proxies of classes by inheriting your entities (hence why you have to define all your fields as `virtual`).

What I would do is instead of your interfaces here, use abstract classes, e.g.

```
public abstract class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<AccessPermission> AccessPermissions { get; protected set; }
}
```

Then (using [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/))

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.HasMany(x => x.AccessPermissions);
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
    }
}
```

and for your sub-classes:

```
public class ReaderMap : SubClassMap<Reader>
{
    public ReaderMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue("Reader");
        this.Map(x => x.Email);
    }
}
```

for your `AccessPermission`:

```
public class AccessPermissionMap : ClassMap<AccessPermission>
{
    public AccessPermissionMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.References(x => x.Object);
        this.References(x => x.Subject);
    }
}
```

Then NH does all the hard work for you and will figure out what sub-class to instantiate based on the FK id in your `AccessPermission`

Comment: In your example, the `User` contains a list of `AccessPermission` objects. This seems like an inversion of responsibility to me. Could there be a solution in which none of the classes have any knowledge of `AccessPermission`?

Comment: Well in the first instance you could always set them to protected rather than public. I think that will work.